# DJANGO: How to make validation of multiple forms based on class based views?

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have the problem with validating two forms at once. Help me, please. I need to validate field **username**, but, as I understand, I cant pass **user_form** to form_invalid method.

```
class TrainerCreateView(ActiveOnlyMixin, BrandOwnersPermissionMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = TrainerForm
    model = Trainer
    second_form_class = UserCreationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrainerCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_form'] = self.second_form_class

    def form_valid(self, form):
        .......

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))



from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Имя')
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Фамилия')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "username", "password1", "password2", 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Username "%s" is already in use.' % username)
        return username
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as nobody knows, I solved the problem by changing models, I mean form_class and second_form_class. So, I cant validate two forms at once still, but I can validate the main form (user registration details), may be this info will be helpful for somebody.

```
class TrainerCreateView(BrandOwnersPermissionMixin, CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    second_form_class = TrainerForm
    template_name = 'panel/accounts/trainer_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrainerCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            trainer_form = TrainerForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            with transaction.atomic():
                if form.is_valid() and trainer_form.is_valid():
                    user = form.save()
                    trainer = trainer_form.save(commit=False)
                    trainer.user_id = user.id
                    trainer_group = Group.objects.get(name='trainers')
                    trainer_group.user_set.add(user)
                    trainer.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url(self))

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```